# Privilege Reputation requirements seem very low

Tags: discussion

The Repulation requirements for Privileges seem very low on SharePoint SE compared to StackOverflow.  Is this temporary (during the Beta), an accident or just how we roll at SharePoint SE?

SharePoint SE Privileges: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges

StackOverflow Privileges: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

---

For Comparison:

```
                            SharePoint    StackOverflow
Trusted User:                  2,000         20,000
Access to Moderator Tools:     1,000         10,000
Edit Questions and Answers:      500          2,000
Vote Down:                         1            125
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that most (if not all) SE Beta sites do.  I was in the Android Enthusiasts beta as well, and during beta the rep requirements are all severely cut down to allow for easier feature testing.

Comment: when the site goes from Beta to live, do the requirements jump back up?  Assumably, we will all be rolling in the rep by then, but if not, do we lose our precious privileges?

Comment: @theChrisKent - Yes, the rep requirements will go back to a "normal" level when the site leaves beta, and yes, this will have an impact on the privileges available to users who are present during beta.

Answer (score 7):

There's actually *three* levels of reputation requirements a site goes through from initial launch, through graduation.

- Private beta reduced reputation requirements
- Public beta levels
- Lunched site (graduation)

Since everyone started out with 1-rep, we have bumped everything down to the [reduced reputation requirements](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq) typically associated with a site's *private* beta.  — It's to help jump start the community activity.

Of course, we didn't want the existing SharePoint Overflow users to suddenly hit the "private beta wall", so we launched the site as a *public* beta, but with the private beta reputation levels. The requirements will be returned to the normal, public beta levels once the previous posts have been restored, and so on through graduation.